# How do you use Twig include statement with FuelPHP?

Tags: php, twig, fuelphp

I have FuelPHP setup to use Twig as the parser. However the include Twig statement {% include 'viewFileNameInsideSameDirectory.twig' %} does not work. I receive the following error:

Unexpected token "name" of value

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using single quotes as shown in the Twig docs, however it only works with double quotes.

{% include "viewFolder/viewFileName.twig" %}